# Pandas: Concatenating two Series to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

How can I concatenate two Series and create one DataFrame ?
For example, I have series like:

```
a=pd.Series([1,2,3])
b=pd.Series([4,5,6])
```

And, I want to get a data frame like:

```
pd.DataFrame([[1,4], [2,5], [3,6]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or use `concat`:

```
>>> pd.concat([a,b],axis=1)
   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
>>>
```

Or `join`:

```
>>> a.to_frame().join(b.to_frame(name=1))
   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Shortest would be:

```
pd.DataFrame([a,b]).T
```

Or:

```
pd.DataFrame(zip(a,b))

   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible faster solution could be,

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((a,b)).T)
```